# Questions about php.net's tutorial on Anonymous Functions

Tags: php

Example 3 of PHP.net's [documentation on anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) has thrown me for a loop.

The first echo statement prints the value of $message even though the documentation leads me to believe this would not work.

> Closures may also inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such variables must be passed to the use language construct. :

```
// No "use"
$example = function () {
    var_dump($message);
};
echo $example();
```

Instead of failing, the output is:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: message in /example.php on line 6
NULL
string(5) "hello"
```

Before the 3rd echo statement, this appears:

```
$message = 'world';
```

And then, echo calls the function, $example again to get the value of $message. The output is `string(5) "hello"` again instead of `string(5) "world"`. Since the value $message was defined when $example was defined, the echo statement still returns `string(5) "hello"`. I get this.

Next, $message is "reset" to "hello". Echo is called again but this time the function $example has a reference to $message:

```
$example = function () use (&$message) {
    var_dump($message);
};
```

The output is `string(5) "world"`. I don't understand this at all. I thought the value of message had been reset to hello?

Why does the first echo still work? Why does the 4th one print "world"?

Comment: Hmm, isn't the first echo statement the `NULL`?

Comment: The first one simply results in NULL -- and `Notice: Undefined variable: message `, which tells you that it "failed". It will not produce a fatal error, and no you won't get a 'hello' out of that one alone.

Comment: I wish it was. It still prints `string(5) "hello"
` In this paste bin, I've numbered the echo statements: http://pastebin.com/yvznijGa. If I comment out the first echo statement the NULL warning disappears but (as far as I can tell) the first var_dump still prints the value of $message, "hello".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Example output

```
Notice: Undefined variable: message in /example.php on line 6
1: NULL
2: string(5) "hello"
3: string(5) "hello"
4: string(5) "hello"
5: string(5) "world"
6: string(11) "hello world"
```

### First Echo Example

From the example code, the first `echo` statement appears to simply result in `NULL` as there's been no `use` included for this anonymous function. *(The `Notice` lets you know that `$message` is undefined.)*

Here is the [relevant code in context](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) for reference:

```
$message = 'hello';

// No "use"
$example = function () {
    var_dump($message);
};
echo $example();
```

### Fifth Echo Example

While the value of `$message` has been reset to `hello`, the following code section:

```
// Inherit by-reference
$example = function () use (&$message) {
    var_dump($message);
};
echo $example();
```

shows that `$message` is inherited [by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) which means that when `$message = 'world';` is used later, we are now referring *(and assigning `"world"`)* to the same `$message` variable as earlier.

In other words, when we define the `$example` function, we are pointing to the original `$message` variable in memory *(via the `&$message` reference)*. So when we call `$example()` later in the code, we are referring to the same, original `$message` variable *(that we've also recently changed with the `$message = 'world';` line)*. This means that `$example()` will output our current `$message` value *(which is currently set to `"world"`)* rather than a previously set value.

Here is the [relevant code in context](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) for reference:

```
// Reset message
$message = 'hello';

// Inherit by-reference
$example = function () use (&$message) {
    var_dump($message);
};
echo $example();

// The changed value in the parent scope
// is reflected inside the function call
$message = 'world';
echo $example();
```

Comment: Thanks. Your numbering of the output encouraged me to re-evaluate the code example. This is only my second day with PHP - I had not taken into account that the last call of $example was printing to output.

Comment: No problem! You are already pretty far along if you are getting into anonymous functions on your second day :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have mixed up the `var_dump` values which lead to the confusion. Let's break down each:

Set the message initially

`$message = 'hello';`

Define the function. Use `$message` as it's **current value**
at the time the function was defined. So here, unless `$example` is re-defined, the output will always be `string(5) "hello"` because that is what `$message` was set to when the function was defined.

```
$example = function () use ($message) {
    var_dump($message);
};
echo $example(); // Result = string(5) "hello"
```

Even though we switch the value of `$message`
the original function uses the value of `$message` when
the function was defined, hence the output of `string(5) "hello"`

```
$message = 'world';
echo $example(); // Result = string(5) "hello"
```

Reset message to "hello" before proceeding to next example

`$message = 'hello';`

When using the `&$message` definition, this is saying "use the **current** value of `$message`" and **NOT** to retain the value of `$message` at the time the function was defined. So, since `$message` currently is set to `"hello"`, the function represents that. If we change `$message` to something else and run the function again, it will dump whatever `$message` value was set.

```
$example = function () use (&$message) {
    var_dump($message);
};
echo $example(); // Result = string(5) "hello"
```

This shows that the `&$message` value is updated in the function when the value changes outside.

```
$message = 'world';
echo $example(); // Result = string(5) "world"
```